# Delete Remote SVN repo

Tags: svn

I have a svn repo that I need to delete (i.e. obliterate entirely). Most means of accomplishing this require the ability to use svnadmin, but this is not an option for me because I do not know what machine holds the actual repository and not just a local copy. Is there some way to delete a repository without having svnadmin privileges, find which machine holds the repo, or some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this repository is a file based one (and not a Berkley-DB one) all you need to do is find where the repository is hosted and delete the root folder of the repository. In fact you cannot do this using svndamin.

Again assuming the repository is hosted behind an apache server using mod_dav_svn, the subversion URL should point you to the correct server. The apache host config files will then point you to the root of the repository file.

As an example an apache config for a subversion installation on apache could look something like this depending on how it was configured.

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath         "/net/svn.nfs/repositories"
</Location>
```

or maybe something like:

```
<Location /svn/myrepo>
  DAV svn
  SvnPath      "/var/svn/myrepo"
</Location>
```

You can then identify from these paths where your repository lives.